# Google Play Services: AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest

On some devices (very very few to be honest), I get this exception on the fragment OnCreateView. Is it a bug in the Google Play Services?

**java.lang.IllegalStateException**:

*The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7895000 but found 8298000.  You must have the following declaration within the `<application>` element: `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`*

Comment: Just update `google_play_services lib` in your IDE.

Comment: @MD what I should do exactly?
on the Gradle file I have already updated the Google Play Services version

Comment: @MD mmm, are you sure? the `google_play_services_version` value already reports 8298000, which is the correct one

Comment: it looks like a bug in Google Play Services to me, it only happens for a tiny percents of devices

Comment: IIRC, this indicates that the device needs an update to Play Services. Before launching some fragment that depends upon Play Services, you need to follow the instructions to check to see if the Play Services on the device is up to date.

Comment: @CommonsWare What is `IIRC`?

Comment: @MD If I Recall Correctly

Comment: @CommonsWare I am actually doing the check on the OnStart of the Activity. I think for some reasons, some devices still load the fragment (and crash), while some devices don't. But I am really talking of 0.01% of devices.

Comment: `onStart()` may be too late, depending on where and how you are showing the fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare so probably the activity's `onCreate()` is a better place for this check?

Comment: That's where I'd do it. In particular, if you are using static fragments, I'd do it before `setContentView()`. Most, if not all, of my MapsV2 samples are set up that way: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2

Comment: @CommonsWare the reason why I was doing it in the `onStart()` is to cut down the loading time of the app. As in `onStart()` the activity is already visible. The call I make there is to `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)`.
I can see the crash happens in the `OnCreateView()` of the fragment as there the `AdView` (which is a Google Play Services class) gets first instantiated.